# How to post all file in the list? | Jquery - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, post, phpmailer

I have a script (index.php) to create a list of all added files from "browse file" button. And I have a script (process.php) to send all files on the list to email with phpmailer.

My problem is, only file(s) at the last click that sent. File(s) that have been added previously unsent.

index.php script

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="data" action="process.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple"/>
    <div id="output"><ul></ul></div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>
</body>
<script>
$("#file").change(function() {
    var ele = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));
    var result = ele.files;
    for(var x = 0; x < result.length; x++){
        var file = result[x];
        $("#output ul").append("<li>" + file.name + "</li>");   
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

process.php script

```
<?php
require 'mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$to = 'destination@email.com';
$subject = 'Test';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$attachment_name = $_FILES['files']['name'];
$attachment_type = $_FILES['files']['type'];
$attachment = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];

include 'smtp.php';

$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->msgHTML('Tes');

foreach($attachment_name as $key => $att){
    $nama_file = $attachment_name[$key];
    $tmp_file = $attachment[$key];

    $mail->addAttachment($tmp_file, $nama_file);
}

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo '<script>alert("Fail"); </script>';
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("Success"); </script>';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have success create multiple input tag for upload file. (using jquery)

And at the php side:

```
// first file
$_FILES['files']['name'][0];
$_FILES['files']['type'][0];
$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0];

// second file
$_FILES['files']['name'][1];
$_FILES['files']['type'][1];
$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][1];
```

OR:

```
$total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

// Loop through all files
for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
    //do what you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it first :)

Comment: When I choose two sequential files, $total just give one value (one file, not two files)

Comment: Oh, you need multiple input tag

Comment: Is there any other way than using multiple input?

Comment: I think there is not a easy wat

Answer (score 0):

**Your current code is unsafe**. Read [the PHP docs on handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

You can attach multiple files using a single file input tag if you set a `multiple` attribute on it, like this;

```
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" multiple="multiple">
```

The 'send_multiple_file_upload` example provided with PHPMailer handles this correctly. The inportant part is:

```
//Attach multiple files one by one
for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
    } else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion bro :). Actually, I have add multiple attribute on input tag. But, I want user can add files continuously using one input tag (type=file). Is that possible?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by continuously here - do you mean you want to be able to add files while an upload is already in progress? To do that would require a JS-driven approach, not possible with plain HTML.

Comment: What I mean is to make uploading file(s) like attachment in gmail. So, user can adding file continuosly from different folder on local computer. First, the file(s) included in the list, and then the file(s) will be processed simultaneously.

Comment: Like I said, you need to use a JS-based upload handler [like this](http://code.runnable.com/UZKDAYo3XEw2AACX/how-to-upload-a-file-using-jquery-for-php). Once you've got the files uploaded, you can pass them in to PHPMailer, which has nothing to do with the actual upload process.

Comment: I was try using JQuery plugin with upload handler. But when I send two files as attachment, it will be sent as two email. Do you know, how do I change the upload handler, so it can send two files in one email